# Can I watch URL request/response on my android app

Tags: android, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm developing an android web browser-ish app. I need to watch (or filter) every request/response when user browsing internet through it.

Under windows I can use fiddlercore to do so. I think NSURL protocol should work on iOS. Is there a way to do it on Android?